# Mutable fields of records with multiple files

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, mutable, imperative-programming

I'm working with multiple files, and i have a problem with one mutable field.
In file1.ml, i declared:

```
type mytype = {
     mutable numbers : int list;
}
```

So, in file2.ml, i have elements of type mytype. But, when i'm trying to make:

```
myElement.numbers
```

The following error is returned: Error: Unbound record field label numbers.

Thanks, any help is welcome.

Comment: One way to think about it is that the thing you're defining is not record, but record selectors. So when you use a selector, you have to state its full path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a fully qualified name from file2: `myElement.File1.numbers`

or add an `open File` to your file.

or use local module opens `let open File2 in myElement.numbers`

Comment: Worked with the first option! But, i forget to explain that my File1.ml has one module, and myType is inserted in "myModule". How can i fix it with "open File"? "open myModule"?

Comment: You should be able to use `open File1.myModule`. Stylistically it's good to work toward having only a very few global uses of `open` in your code. Otherwise you have to work too hard to keep your namespaces free of conflicting names. If you're just starting with OCaml you can worry about this later.

Comment: note that this "problem" should disappear with future versions of OCaml (there was already working code in the development tree last time I tried it).